# Deserialize JSON in C# to array and iterate

Tags: c#, json, json.net, restsharp, json-deserialization

I need help to know what I am doing wrong, I have little time working with c#. I can't iterate the json , I am using RestSharp and Newtonsoft.Json .  The message says::

> "'Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'ConsoleApp1.Libro' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
>   To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. "

if I print the response.Content it returns the correct json, but I can't iterate it with the foreach

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Libro
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string id_categoria { get; set; }
        public string tipo { get; set; }
        public string ruta { get; set; }
        public string autor { get; set; }
        public int estado { get; set; }
        public string titulo { get; set; }
        public string titular { get; set; }
        public int size { get; set; }
        public string detalles { get; set; }
        public double precio { get; set; }
        public string portada { get; set; }
        public int ventas { get; set; }
        public int oferta { get; set; }
        public double precioOferta { get; set; }
        public int entrega { get; set; }
        public string fecha { get; set; }
    }

    public class Cate
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string categoria { get; set; }
        public string ruta { get; set; }
        public int estado { get; set; }
        public int oferta { get; set; }
        public int precioOferta { get; set; }
        public int descuentoOferta { get; set; }
        public string imgOferta { get; set; }
        public string finOferta { get; set; }
        public string fecha { get; set; }
        public IList<Libro> libros { get; set; }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("mostrar registros");
            var client = new RestClient("myurl");
            client.Timeout = -1;
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            var resultado = new Libro();
            resultado = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Libro>(response.Content); /*(here is the error)*/

            foreach (var item in resultado.titulo)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is in your response.Content? Can you add that to your post. I am pretty sure you either have square brackets in your response.Content so if that is the case you will need to trim them or you can just deserialize in a list than get the zero index if you need the first one.

Comment: https://app.quicktype.io/#l=cs&r=json2csharp - almost all JSON issues will disappear if you use the right types.

Comment: In your `public class Cate` you have `public IList<Libro> libros { get; set; }`. You probably need to `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Cate>(response.Content);`. Posting the JSON would make it easier (may also change `IList` to `List`).

Answer (score 0):

If there are square brackets in your response.Content, that could cause the problem. If that is the case, either try:

```
resultado  = JSON.Deserialize<Libro>(response.Content.Substring(1, response.Content.Length-2));
```

or you can also deserialize in a list and use the zero index to get the first one. Something like:

```
var resultadoList   = JSON.Deserialize<List<Libro>>(response.Content);
resultado = resultadoList[0];
```

or

```
var resultadoList   = JSON.Deserialize<List<Libro>>(response.Content);
resultado = resultadoList.FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go:

```
Libro[] resultados = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Libro[]>(response.Content);

foreach (var resultado in resultados)
    foreach (var item in resultado.titulo)
        Console.WriteLine(item);
```